# Can the new iPad Pro magic keyboard used on Dvorak?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ipados, dvorak

I wonder if it is possible to use Dvorak layout on the new Magic Keyboard for iPad Pro. It would be even better if I can use it without installing any third-party keyboard applications.

Also, on Mac I swapped some keys (; and ') but can I also swap the keys at my will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just go to settings/general/keyboard/hardware keyboard and tap over at the right edge and select Dvorak.

[image]

Comment: Today I tried on a demo iPad on Apple Store, and found out that this setting is applied only to English keyboard. Chinese and Japanese keyboard only have QWERTY and/or AZERTY options...

Comment: That's correct.  To see what mappings are available for each you can check my list at https://thgewecke.github.io/mlingmac/ios11kbs.html  (which is probably still pretty accurate)